# memcpy from a vector to void pointer (vice-versa) not working

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memcpy

This is struct node with 2 variables.

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
}node;
```

Inserting the values into vector of the node type.

```
    vector <node> nv;
    node n;

    n.a = 10;
    n.b = 20;
    nv.push_back(n);

    n.a = 100;
    n.b = 200;
    nv.push_back(n);
```

Copying the vector to a void pointer.

```
    void *ptr = malloc(4096);
    memcpy((char*)ptr,&nv,sizeof(node)*2);
```

Reading the values from the void pointer

```
    node *temp;

    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    int offset = 0;
    i = 0;
    while(i<n){
        memcpy((node*)temp,(char*)ptr + offset, sizeof(node));
        cout<<"a - "<<temp->a<<" b -"<<temp->b<<endl;
        offset += sizeof(node);
        i++;
    }
```

I am printing the values of a and b. But they are incorrect and contains random numbers. I am sure that I am hitting the wrong memory location. But not sure where.

Comment: replace `&nv` with `nv.data()`

Comment: Re: "Copying the vector to a void pointer" -- no, No, NO. The code copies the data to an array of bytes that's pointed to by a void pointer. Keep that distinction firmly in mind: a pointer **points at** something, and mostly you care about what it points at.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` object is not an array object. The vector manages a dynamically allocated array. Just like your `ptr` isn't an array, but simply points to one.

Just like you musn't pass `&ptr` to `malloc` (as that would cause the data to be written over the pointer, not the pointed array), so too you musn't pass `&nv` (as that would cause the data to be read from vector which manages the array, rather than from the array which is being managed). Vector has a member function `data` which returns a pointer to the internal array.

Comment: In that case, how can I write an object to a buffer? I tried static arrays, they work well. But in my case the problem is that I don't have the array size known in prior.